# Control-L to enter path in Gnome-shell save dialog

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell

In Gnome, I used to be able to manually enter where I wanted to save a file from the save dialog by hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. This would focus an editable text box above the file chooser. This appears to not work on current versions of Gnome (I'm using Gnome Shell 3.12.2 on Arch Linux but it's been gone for a few versions I think). The regular Nautilus file browser still has this functionality.

Is there a knob I need to frobulate to get this functionality back?